# Why am I getting blank records when using PXDatabase.GetSlot to retrieve data from a table?

Tags: acumatica

I set up this IPrefetchable class because I needed to store a set of data in memory for quick access to it and wanted it returned as a dictionary. I'm using PXDatabase.GetSlot to save data from INItemLotSerial into a pxdatabase slot, however when dbRecords selects the records from it, the field values in it are null(lotserialnbr, inventoryID, etc) although it does return the correct count of records. This is my first time using PXDatabase.GetSlot so perhaps I'm missing something fairly simple.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
    class INItemLotSerialFetcher : IPrefetchable
    {
        private Dictionary<string, int?> _availlist = new Dictionary<string, int?>();
        
        public void Prefetch()
        {
            // read database
            var dbRecords = PXDatabase.Select<INItemLotSerial>();


            //add results to Dictionary
            foreach (var rec in dbRecords)
            {
                if (rec.LotSerialNbr != null)
                {
                _availlist.Add(rec.LotSerialNbr, rec.InventoryID);
                }
            }

        }

        public static Dictionary<string, int?> GetINList()
        {
            var def = GetSlot();
            return def._availlist;
        }
        private static INItemLotSerialFetcher GetSlot()
        {
            return PXDatabase.GetSlot<INItemLotSerialFetcher>("INserialFetcherSlot", typeof(INItemLotSerial));
            
        }

    }
```

Comment: Did you try getting the slotname doing somethng like this instead:    string slotName = typeof(INItemLotSerialFetcher).ToString();
   var slot = PXDatabase.GetSlot<INItemLotSerialFetcher>(slotName , typeof(INItemLotSerial));

Answer (score 0):

Try this change ala [an example from Sergey Marenich](https://gist.github.com/smarenich/a604af2dd4ede9c6cd86)

```
public static Dictionary<string, int?> GetINList()
{
   return PXDatabase.GetSlot<INItemLotSerialFetcher>("INserialFetcherSlot", typeof(INItemLotSerial));            
}
```